# class based detail view is not returning the template

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-class-based-views, detailsview

In my article_details.html page I have written {{post.title}} but my the page is not showing the specific title. My app name is post and the model name is BlogPost.
this is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from django.views.generic import ListView,CreateView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
def home(request):
return render(request,'post/home.html')

class HomeView(ListView):
      model = BlogPost
      template_name = "post/home2.html"

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
           model = BlogPost
          template_name = "post/article_details.html"
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = "post/add_post.html"
    fields = '__all__'
```

this is my urls.py

```
from post import views
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomeView,ArticleDetailView,AddPostView
app_name = 'post'
urlpatterns = [
         path('',views.home,name="home"),
         path('home2/',HomeView.as_view(),name = "home2"),
         path('article/<int:pk>',ArticleDetailView.as_view(),name = "article-details"),
         path('add_post/',AddPostView.as_view(),name="add_post"),
    ]
```

this is my list page: post/home2.html

```
<ul>
{%for post in object_list %}
    <li><a href="{%url 'post:article-details' post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a>-{{post.author}}<br/>
     {{post.body}}</li>
{%endfor%}
 </ul>
```

and this is my detail page:article_details.html:

```
<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
<small>by:{{post.author}}</small><br/>
<hr>
<br/>
<p>{{post.body}}</p>



enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you define [`context_object_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.context_object_name), the view will send the object via context perameter of your model name in all lower case. So you should get value via `{{ blogpost.author }}`. Or, you can update your view like:

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
      model = BlogPost
      template_name = "post/article_details.html"
      context_object_name = 'post'
```

Please see the [documentation on context object naming](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name) for more details.